# What do I put in the "ifSuccessfulSendTo" field in a crowdsale contract

Tags: contract-deployment

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable public {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
       emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() public afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() public afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                   emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
               emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the image of what I need to fill in when deploying the contract:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line `beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;` tells you that it will be the beneficiary.

Later, you see that `beneficiary.send(amountRaised)`. So this will be the address to which you want to see Ether money raised go.

So pick an address you control and put that one in here.

Comment: I have done that and the tokens are never actually bought or at least the proceeds don't show up in the account I chose and the account I send test ether from never receives the tokens.

Comment: Is the condition `if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender)` satisfied when you attempt to withdraw?

Comment: I thought it automatically sent the funds if funding goal was met. It never did and the account that I sent test ether from never received the tokens. The funding goal was 2 test ether and the time was for 10 minutes.

Comment: The code says it takes contributions in. Then you call `checkGoalReached`, then you withdraw. It is the classic inversion of control found in many contracts: do proper accounting and let the interested party take the money.

Comment: So, my lack of knowledge and experience compels me to ask if what you wrote above is a good thing. Also, how do I call the checkGoalReached function?

Comment: Actually, I started by asking how to remove those functions so I think I have gotten off track from my original intent.

Comment: After you have deployed the contract, Remix will show you `checkGoalReached` as a callable function. Inversion of control, is a good thing, this is what you want from a smart contract. So `safeWithdrawal` is good. I think `checkGoalReached` could be rolled up inside `safeWithdrawal`.

Comment: The (fallback), checkGoalReached and safeWithdrawable functions are in red when I open the deployed contract section. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that invoking them will create a transaction.